# POST variable - XHTTP, PHP

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to pass a variable through to PHP using XHTTP.

```
console.log("js date: " + date);

  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","includes/stats.inc.php?date="+date,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```

In the PHP:

```
$dateToday = $_POST['date'];
echo $dateToday;
echo "demo"
```

"demo" is being echoed into the console.log, but nothing is coming from echo `echo $dateToday;` - it seems $dateToday has no value. Any ideas?

Comment: The parameter itself is passed on the URL, so it will be a `$_GET` value rather than `$_POST`.

Comment: Great, thank you very much @NigelRen! It works now